# Android keyboard does not show when pressing input text box

Tags: android, iframe, keyboard, webkit, textinput

I am trying to implement an iframe with a search-box in my web page.

The thing is that I have a web-page from one domain let say this page is http:///myPage.html
and I have in its html an iframe element which reference to another html on a different domain. let say the element is like so /iframe_content.html">

and in the http:///iframe_content.html page I have an input text box I want to use as a search-box.

The problem is when I surf with Android 2.2 to my original web-page, I see the iframe I embed in my html and when I press the input-text-box I don't see the virtual keyboard Android browser should supply in-order to insert some text into it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you serve the input text box page from the same domain? Does the keyboard appear?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and extend it with webview

```
private class MwebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        waitDialog.setMessage("Loading Page...");
        waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        waitDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (waitDialog != null) {
            waitDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
        super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
```

//forcefully show keyboard, and then it will show keyboard on any text field key press

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN, InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
        }
    }
```

And now when ever you click on any text field it will show the keyboard. First time it might show keyboard on page load with out any user interaction.